# create react app is creating the project in typescript

Tags: reactjs

I'm using:

```
npx create-react-app myproj
```

but my react is creating the app in typescript mode, i'm using the last versions updated create-react-app

any ideas why is using by default typescript ?  i've tried:

Comment: You can't create .js files and make it work ?

Comment: How did you understand that the app is created in typescript mode? Can you show?

Comment: Weird, as a workaround you can tell explicitly to use the default template: ```npx create-react-app myproj --template cra-template```

Comment: hello, now it's working well, very rare ! thanks @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon i keep your solution in the case happens again